# A $*$-homomorphism $C(X) \to C(Y)$ gives a continuous map $Y \to X$

Tags: gn.general-topology, c-star-algebras

Given a $C^*$-algebra $A$, we write $\Omega(A)$ for its space of characters, i.e. its non-zero algebra homomorphisms $A \to \mathbb{C}$. If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, it is well-known that
$$X \to \Omega(C(X)): x \mapsto \operatorname{ev}_x$$
is a homeomorphism of topological spaces.

---

Let $X,Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces.

Let a $*$-homomorphism $\pi: C(X) \to C(Y)$ be given. Then we can associate a continuous map $Y \to X$ by the composition
$$Y \cong \Omega(C(Y)) \to \Omega(C(X)) \cong X$$
where the middle map sends $\chi \mapsto \chi\circ \pi.$

---

Question: Is it possible to explicitly write down a formula for this map $Y \to X$? I guess this can be answered if we can write down an explicit inverse for the homeomorphism
$$X \to \Omega(C(X)).$$

Comment: I guess you are looking for a formula for $\pi^*:Y\to X$ in terms of $\pi$? I think that in some sense this may be a misguided POV, in that what Gelfand duality tells us here is that any unital star-hom $\pi$ must be of the form $\pi(f)(y) = f(\theta(y))$ for some continuous map $\theta:Y\to X$, and so any $\pi$ which you can write down must come from some $\theta$ that you can also write down.

Comment: This seems related to the principle that one can have a natural map which is shown to be injective and surjective, but where there is no "explicit formula" for the inverse of this map.

Comment: About Yemon Choi's last comment, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180665/ where I also posted an answer partially refuting that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq C(X)$, the corresponding point $x \in X$ or rather its singleton $\{x\}$ is the intersection of all zero sets $Z(f)$ of all functions $f \in \mathfrak{m}$.

So the map $\varphi : Y \to X$ associated to $\pi : C(X) \to C(Y)$ is defined by
$$\{\varphi(y)\} = \bigcap_{f \in C(X),\, \pi(f)(y)=0} Z(f).$$
But as Yemon Choi points out, $\pi(f)=f \circ \varphi$ can also be seen as the definition of $\varphi$!

Comment: Using the description of the spectrum of $C(X)$ in terms of characters instead of maximal ideals, this answer amounts to $\{\phi(y)\}=\operatorname{supp}\pi^\ast(\mathrm{ev}_y)$.